# Python - what does "add property for the field" do?

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, protected

I'm developing a python program in pycharm. Under this line of my code:

```
rut = Tk()
rut.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', rut._w, PhotoImage(file=icon_file))
```

And I get a warning on 'rut._w' saying:

> access to a protected member _w of a class

And when I press ctrl + enter it gives me an option:

> add property for the field

And when I click on it it changes the line to:

```
rut.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', rut.w, PhotoImage(file=icon_file))
```

But I know that is not all what it does because if I manually change the name I will get:

> AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'w'

So what is happening here? what what does _w mean and what about .w and what does it mean to *add property for the field* and how is it actually done?

Please note that Tk is imported from the tkinter package which is not in my project files so I suppose pycharm can't edit it.

Comment: `rut` is an instance of `Tk` . PyCharm seems to be defining a `w` property for `Tk` instance in the source of the `Tk` class.

Comment: Tk is imported from tkinter package which is not in my project files so I suppose pycharm can't edit it.(sorry I should have clarified this in the question. I will now)@OluwafemiSule

Comment: Does you application run successfully when Pycharm changes the attribute to `w`? AFAIK, [TK doesn't have a `w` attribute defined](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1996) If your applications run successfully, you must know somehow that Pycharm is monkey-patching that in. See my answer for how you can get around to not using a private property

Comment: @OluwafemiSule yes it runs successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`__str__` method defined for Tk returns `self._w`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L1492) *i.e.* it is a getter for the private property.

You can use:

```
rut.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', str(rut), PhotoImage(file=icon_file))
```

---

What Pycharm is doing is adding this to `Tkinter` class. This is bad because your application is guaranteed to work on your machine but not on other machines where the `Tkinker` class isn't so patched.

`Cmd + Click` or `Ctrl + Click`  *(depending on your platform)* on the `Tk()` in `rut = Tk()` to open the class definition. You'll see this added at the end.

```
@property
def w(self):
    return self._w
```

Comment: can you also explain to me what does add property for the field do?

Comment: Please see my explanation.

Comment: wow, that is a really silly feature to add to the IDE...